# How to center the name of nomencl?

Tags: sectioning, horizontal-alignment, nomenclature

I am writing my thesis and need to use the `nomenclature` package to make a list of symbols.

Initially I get a list of symbols, making the entire procedure that specifies the help of this package.

But I need is center the name of the nomenclature as follows:

```
                 List of Symbols

   A  Symbol A
   B  Symbol B
```

How can I achieve this alignment?

Comment: It is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `\printnomenclature` macro of the [`nomencl` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/nomencl) typesets the header of the nomenclature list as a `\chapter*` (in `book`, `report` or other document class supporting `\chapter`) or as a `\section*` (in `article` or other document classes). The title is given by `\nomname`. The easiest way to center this heading is to renew `\nomname` as a centered box:

```
\renewcommand{\nomname}{\makebox[\linewidth]{List of Symbols}}%
```

`\makebox` will center its contents by default.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use `\centering` instead of `\makebox`. `\makebox` will cause the "List of Symbols" in the table of contents also to be centered. So better use
`\renewcommand{\nomname}{\centering{List of Symbols}}`.